# Bluetooth keyboard not showing up in /dev/input

Tags: debian, keyboard, devices, udev, bluetooth

I've just installed an Apple Wireless keyboard on a Debian system. I used [this guide](http://www.correlatedcontent.com/blog/bluetooth-keyboard-on-the-raspberry-pi/) and only console tools — no X on that machine yet.

The keyboard works fine. Now I want to remap a right Cmd key using keyfuzz and create a rule in udev, just like it's done [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/un-apple-keyboard).

The problem is, my keyboard isn't showing up in `/dev/input`:

```
# ls /dev/input/by-id
usb-A4Tech_USB_Mouse-event-mouse  usb-A4Tech_USB_Mouse-mouse
```

It also doesn't show up in `lsusb`:

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 17cc:1001 Native Instruments 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 011 Device 002: ID 09da:0080 A4 Tech Co., Ltd
```

So also no keyboard here.

Why doesn't it show up? How to find out `idVendor` and `idProduct` needed for udev? How to address the keyboard in a keyfuzz script which needs a `/dev/input/` path?

Comment: Try 'hcitool scan' http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/hcitool1.html